# MariaDB Rows matched: 15135 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0

Tags: mysql, mariadb, update

So...

I find this to be strange:

```
UPDATE cFlights c  
LEFT JOIN airports a on a.IATA = c.depCode  
SET c.depId = a.id, c.depName = a.name  
where c.depCode!='' and c.depName is null;
```

I know that table design is not ideal, but I am not sure why update does not work?

Output is:

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (1 min 28.94 sec) Rows matched: 15135 
>   Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: This mean that 15135 records matched join and where conditions, but none of them have old data (in `depId` or `depName` fields of `cFlights` table) which differs from new one (from `airports` table).

Comment: @Akina but I find that hard to believe since if I count how many records has null or '' value for depCode or depName I get 6372 results in total

Comment: why is it a LEFT JOIN. You're  setting c.depId to a.id (which could be null in LEFT JOIN case)

Comment: Replace `UPDATE` with `SELECT DISTINCT cFlights.* FROM` and comment SET clause - you will see all records which will be updated. Replace above SELECT with `SELECT * FROM` for to see the values which will be assigned from and to.